# "Could not Find Corpus"

Tags: r

I am trying to write a simple code in R in order to create a text mining practice, however, I am receiving an error message:

```
"could not find Function "Corpus"
```

Would appreciate if you could help me out

PFA the Screenshot for reference:
[image: PFA the Screenshot for reference].

Comment: Line 11 : _typo error_ , fix to `Corpus(.....)` function

Comment: It should be either `Corpus()` or `VCorpus()` function

Comment: you forget to load the package after restarting the session

Comment: hi guys, thank you for your feedback, but still doesn't seem to work. any other way of optimizing the code